# can't manage to solve why checkbox checked as default don't work

Tags: woocommerce, checkbox

I'm trying to get the approve newsletter in the checkout to be checked as default and it doesn't check it.
any idea why?

```
`function add_newsletter_checkbox() {
    // Display the newsletter checkbox
    echo '<div class="newsletter-checkbox">';
    
    woocommerce_form_field( 'newsletter_checkbox', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label checkbox'),
        'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input checkbox'),
        'required'      => false,
        'label'         => ('Subscribe to our newsletter', 'woocommerce' => array('default' => 1)
        'value'         => true, // Set the value for the checkbox
    ));

    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_terms_and_conditions', 'add_newsletter_checkbox' );
`
```

thanks!

i tried to change the different fields of the code to get it to check as default the checkbox.